# Android MVVM Design pattern (inter-activity communication)

Tags: android, mvvm

What is the best practice when it comes to communicating data between activities following a MVVC design pattern?

The way I structured it currently is as follows:

```
View <-> View Model <-> Model
  ^         ^
   \       /
Activity/Fragment
```

Currently, the app communicates with other activities using Intents in which I pass in the specific model information that that Activity should handle. The intent is received and then parsed and passed to the Model directly after initializing the listeners between view and view model and view model and model.

I am not quite sure if this is a good approach and was wondering if there was a better best practice out there.

Answer (score 0):

We've been Moving to the MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern for our assignments and it seems to work well. Plus you can then think of the 'Activities' as just 'views' (like you are). (Also, can help you move to more 'fragments' and less activities too if done right)

The MVP pattern can help you by giving you more defined interfaces (I mean abstractly or actual Java Interface(s)) between the Views and the Presenter and at the same the Presenter and the Model.

Here is my PhD adviser's github repo where he shows some examples of how to implement the MVP pattern. We have used this example in several Coursera MOOCs and it seems to work well explaining the topic to the learners.

https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/POSA-15/tree/master/ex/AcronymExpander

Here is the Wikipedia Article on MVP pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter